# MapValues and Explode in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this sample RDD below (called `rdd` below). The dataset is a tuple of `(String, Int)`:

```
(some | random | value, 10)
(some | random | value, 11)
(some | random | value, 12)
```

And I want to get this output:

```
(some, 10)
(random, 10)
(value, 10)
(some, 11)
(random, 11)
(value, 11)
(some, 12)
(random, 12)
(value, 12)
```

I have this Scala code to attempt the above transformation:

```
rdd.map(tuple => tuple._1.split("|").foreach(elemInArray => (elemInArray, tuple._2)))
```

In this code I iterate through the entire dataset and split the first part of the tuple by `|`. Then I iterate through each element in that array returned by `split` and create a tuple with each `element` and the count that I get form `tuple._1`.

For some reason I keep getting this result:

```
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
```

Does anyone know the issue? I can't seem to find where I went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually need to use `flatMap` for this:

```
val lt = List(("some | random | value", 10),
              ("some | random | value", 11),
              ("some | random | value", 12))

val convert: ((String, Int)) => List[(String, Int)] = tuple => tuple._1.split('|').map(str =>
  (str, tuple._2)).toList

val t = lt.flatMap(convert)
```

As we can see, defining the `convert` function can be very useful, because we can ensure that each element is correctly handled by passing that function a single element. We can then pass that same function to `flatMap`, which will aggregate the list of results that `convert` produces into a single list.

The above yields:

```
t: List[(String, Int)] = List((some ,10), 
                              ( random ,10), 
                              ( value,10), 
                              (some ,11), 
                              ( random ,11), 
                              ( value,11), 
                              (some ,12), 
                              ( random ,12),
                              ( value,12))
```

Obviously, I didn't bother to deal with the extra whitespace characters in the result, but this is easily handled by updating your `convert` function with `trim`:

```
val convert: ((String, Int)) => List[(String, Int)] = tuple => tuple._1.split('|').map(str =>
  (str.trim, tuple._2)).toList
```