# Not able to split the column into multiple columns in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, multidimensional-array, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Not able to split the column into multiple columns in Spark Data-frame and through RDD.
I tried other some codes but works with only fixed columns.
Ex:

Datatype is `name:string , city =list(string)`

I have a text file and input data is like below

```
Name, city

A, (hyd,che,pune)

B, (che,bang,del)

C, (hyd)
```

Required Output is:

```
A,hyd 

A,che

A,pune

B,che,

C,bang

B,del

C,hyd
```

after reading text file and converting DF.

Data-frame will look like below,

```
scala> data.show
+----------------+
|                 |
|           value |
|                 |
+----------------+

|      Name, city
|
|A,(hyd,che,pune)
|
|B,(che,bang,del)
|
|         C,(hyd)
|
|  D,(hyd,che,tn)|
+----------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005801/mapvalues-and-explode-in-rdd

Comment: nope, here dataset is Array not a tuple

Comment: here your column name in your data is it correct ?

Comment: how do you get tuple in scala dataframe.either you can get a spark struct or an array

Comment: can you provide schema of dataframe

Comment: scala> data.printSchema
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode` function on your DataFrame

```
val explodeDF = inputDF.withColumn("city", explode($"city")).show()
```

http://sqlandhadoop.com/spark-dataframe-explode/

Now that I understood you're loading your full line as a string, here is the solution on how to achieve your output

I have defined two user defined functions

```
val split_to_two_strings: String => Array[String] = _.split(",",2) # to first split your input two elements to convert to two columns (name, city)
val custom_conv_to_Array: String => Array[String] = _.stripPrefix("(").stripSuffix(")").split(",") # strip ( and ) then convert to list of cities

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val custom_conv_to_ArrayUDF = udf(custom_conv_to_Array)
val split_to_two_stringsUDF = udf(split_to_two_strings)


val outputDF = inputDF.withColumn("tmp", split_to_two_stringsUDF($"value"))
  .select($"tmp".getItem(0).as("Name"), trim($"tmp".getItem(1)).as("city_list"))
  .withColumn("city_array", custom_conv_to_ArrayUDF($"city_list"))
  .drop($"city_list")
  .withColumn("city", explode($"city_array"))
  .drop($"city_array")

outputDF.show()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this already, it is not working. here data is a array. when we read this data into spark as a textfile it looks like below, scala> data.show
+----------------+
|           value|
+----------------+
|      Name, city|
|A,(hyd,che,pune)|
|B,(che,bang,del)|
|         C,(hyd)|
|  D,(hyd,che,tn)|
+----------------+

Comment: can you run ```data.printSchema()``` and provide the result?

Comment: scala> data.printSchema
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Ok, so it means you're loading full row as a string, and from your post ```Datatype is name:string , city =list(string)``` I thought city is another column which is Array or list as you mentioned. You need to parse the string (in your case name) to have two columns namely name, city ( should be of type Array) and then only you can try explode

Comment: @user11789810 , I have updated my answer please check